# How to get running Kafka consumers using .NET TestServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, apache-kafka

I need to check which of my Kafka consumers defined in the application are up & running while executing integration test. Is it possible to get this information using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost TestServer?